# Taking website down with app_offline during web deployment through pubxml file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2019, microsoft-web-deploy

I have just recently found out that IIS web deploy 3.0 and newer versions do support feature of taking website down while doing a deployment by using this property inside the .pubxml file:

```
  <EnableMSDeployAppOffline>true</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>
```

This works fine - it generates a file called App_Offline.htm in my website's root directory...

However - the file generated like this is completely empty - but I don't want it to be empty. I wanna place custom HTML there and I cannot seem to find a way to do this. I cannot see from where is this file being generated - nor do I have any clue how to place custom HTML inside that page during web deployment.

Has anyone had a similar issue like this ?

I've checked all the documentation on this but I can't seem to find a solution..:/

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Anyone guys ? =)

Comment: "I've checked all the documentation on this but I can't seem to find a solution" is often the answer itself. The whole Web Deploy system is not open sourced, so what's not in the documentation cannot exist.